# My app doesn't open and force closes

Tags: android

My app force closes as soon as I open it,
this is my first app, and I have tried to find errors, but I can't
I have attached log cat since starting this app:

```
          12-03 16:04:54.040: W/dalvikvm(8798): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
          12-03 16:04:54.040: E/AndroidRuntime(8798): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
          12-03 16:04:54.040: E/AndroidRuntime(8798): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sditya.quadratic.equation/com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic}: java.lang.NullPointerException
          ...
          12-03 16:04:54.040: E/AndroidRuntime(8798): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
          12-03 16:04:54.040: E/AndroidRuntime(8798):   at com.sditya.quadratic.equation.Quadratic.initialize(Quadratic.java:58)
```

The **initialize** method:

```
private void initialize() { 
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
tr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResults); 
xs = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
x = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2); 
c = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3); 
b.setOnClickListener(this); 
}
```

---

**Edit:** Resolved, I forgot to inflate button 'b'.

Comment: What's on line 58 of Quadratic.java ?

Comment: You're referencing a null pointer on line 58 in your initialize method.

Comment: `private void initialize() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  tr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResults);
  xs = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  x = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
  c = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
  b.setOnClickListener(this);
 }`

Comment: Put some lines of your code from line 50 to 60 in Quadratic.java

Comment: check if "b" is inflated from layout...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `initialize` method, you need to set the button variable before setting the listener..

```
private void initialize() { 
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
tr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResults); 
xs = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
x = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2); 
c = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3); 

b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
b.setOnClickListener(this); 
}
```